# cakephp 3.3: pagination and sorting error when model is in url

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.3

I have the following Events controller:

```
public $paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => ['title', 'id', 'price', 'date', 'Categories.description'],
    'order'         => ['date' => 'desc']
];
```

and an index method:

```
$events = $this->Events->find()->contain(['Categories']);
$this->set('events', $this->paginate($events));
```

In my view file I have a table with `echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'code')` and a

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers([
    'separator' => '',
    'currentTag' => 'a',
    'modulus' => 25,
    'currentClass' => 'active',
    'tag' => 'li',
    'first' => 1
]);
```

If I go to page `/events` I get the expected results. If I sort by id and click in page 2 the url shows `events?page=2&sort=Events.id&direction=asc` and the result is not correct.

I see the sql log and no order by clause appears. If I manually edit the url without the model: `events?page=2&sort=id&direction=asc` the result is correct.

am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The sort field is not in your whitelist.

As soon as you configure the `sortWhitelist` the paginator component rejects all other sort parameters.

The paginator component understands the `sort=id` query parameter, and will assume you mean the default model for the pagination, but the helper is following the naming convention for sorting parameters. Which includes the model name. The `sort=id` parameter works because `id` is in your whitelist.

So you have to include `Events` in the `sortWhitelist`

```
public $paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => ['Events.title', 'Events.id', 'Events.price', 'Events.date', 'Categories.description'],
    'order' => ['Events.date' => 'desc']
];
```

Comment: I did this. But then nothing worked. Not event when accessing /events, sql log didn't have an order  by clause.
Sorry for not telling this earlier.

Comment: @gong Does it work if you remove the `sortWhitelist` from the options?